Is ${}_3 F_2(a,b,c;d,e;x)$ irrational for $ a,c,d,e,x \in \mathbb{Q} / \{0 \} $
My understanding of G-functions is simply nonexistent but I do know that they can assume algebraic values at nonzero rational arguments. But could those assumed values be rational?
Specifically I was wandering under what conditions is the generalized hypergeometric series ${}_3 F_2(a,b,c;d,e;x)$ irrational the same way that $\cos x = {}_0 F_1(;\frac{1}{2}; -\frac{x^2}{4}) $ and $\arctan x = x \cdot {}_2 F_1(\frac{1}{2},1;\frac{3}{2}; -x^2) $ are at $x\in \mathbb{Q} / \{0\}$? I suppose that rationality of $a,b,c,d,e$ isn’t enough?
